# Механизм работы виртуальных методов в C#

Tags: c#, virtual, виртуальная-функция

Мне немного не ясен механизм работы виртуальных методов в C#. Знаю, что для каждого класса, имеющего виртуальные методы, есть своя таблица виртуальных методов *VMT*. Знаю, что каждый экземпляр таких классов содержит ссылку на соответствующую VMT. Но не могу полностью понять алгоритм вызова виртуального метода.

Первый шаг - в момент вызова метода "среда исполнения" (условно назовем) берет у целевого объекта адрес VMT, по нему обращается к таблице. Далее наступает "магия", и каким-то образом определяется смещение в таблице виртуальных методов, по которому лежит адрес нужного нам метода, и обращаясь по извлеченному из VMT адресу метода "среда исполнения" извлекает нужную реализацию.

**Вопрос:** как после первого шага определяется смещение, по которому лежит адрес реализации метода, который мы вызвали?

Comment: Скорее всего, "номер строки" (смещение - я правильно вас понял?) определяется во время компиляции, и базовый метод и перегруженный кладутся в свои таблицы по одному и тому же смещению. По сигнатуре метода компилятор смотрит, по какому смещению искать адрес функции в таблице. Но это не точно, просто как я бы сам делал.

Comment: Попробуйте утилиту sos, возможно sos-дампы вам дадут ответ. Да... и подшейте в вопрос дампы и маалекую c# программу, что б можно было это повторить.

Comment: @nick_n_a я дал условное название "номер строки", потому что таблица содержит в себе строки или записи, если говорить в общих понятиях. Я не знаю, как внутри устроена VMT, знаю, что она лишь хранит адреса методов. Если бы она была бы списком, я бы сказал "номер в списке". Так что я так и не понял обоснованность вашего наезда.

Comment: @nick_n_a это не отладка, вы неправильно поняли мой вопрос.

Comment: Что вы делаете, взлом, отладчик, или просто хотите из с# узнать точку входа в метод что б подставить её в с++? *Первый шаг - берем адрес VMT* - откуда берем? Ну не каждый кто пишет на с# так легко его возьмет.

Comment: @nick_n_a я просто хочу узнать, по какому алгоритму вызываются виртуальные методы в C#, вот и все.

Comment: У каждого класса есть таблица виртуальных методов. Алгоритм - ок. Мы обходим таблицу даного класса метод по ключу (token), если метод в таблице не найден - переходим по parent к родительскому классу - повторяем поиск (если не найден - переходим опять, если соовсем не найден - Abstract error). Когда адрес найден - делаем переход. P.S. Создайте в студии маленькую консольную с# программу, подключите модуль SOS. C помощью sos и marshal - раскопайте структуры. Задача нетривиальная не думаю что много людей разбирали VMT на запчасти.

Comment: А почему не поискать на хабре? http://habr.com/ru/company/clrium/blog/344556/

Comment: @nick_n_a ок, я попробую с SOS поработать. Такой вопрос: откуда берется ключ (token)?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko он задан изначально

Comment: @PavelMayorov он определяется на этапе компиляции? тогда где он хранится?

Comment: Прямо в il-коде хранится.

Comment: @nick_n_a это понятно, любая константа будет храниться в IL-коде. А где именно? В описании класса?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko в **коде**

Comment: @PavelMayorov теперь я понял. Спасибо.

Comment: Вот [здесь](http://www.msdr.ru/21/) вроде неплохо объяснено.